# Mat-Autocomplete with FormControlName doesn´t display the value I want

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I´m using the mat autocomplete with the FormControlName and I don´t know why but in the mat-option is displaying a value that I don´t want to display.

Here´s my code:

HTML:

```
<form class="mat-card mat-elevation-z4 p-24 animated fadeIn delay-1s" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start"
             [formGroup]="formCreateRequirement" #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formDirective)">

            <div class="h2 mb-24" fxLayoutAlign="center center">Some text here...</div>

            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex>

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100">
                    <mat-label>Project</mat-label>

                    <input matInput 
                           formControlName="projectId"
                           required
                           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                    
                           <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption
                            >
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let project of filteredprojects  | async" [value]="project.id">
                                    {{project.name}}
                                </mat-option>
                           </mat-autocomplete></form>
```

TS:

```
filterProjects(name: string){
    return this.projects.filter( project => project.name.toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}
```

ngOnInit():{

```
    this.filteredProjects = this.formCreateRequirement.controls.projectId.valueChanges
    .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map( project=>  project? this.filterProjects(project) : this.projects.slice() )
    );
```

}

So, what i´d like to display on the mat-option is the {{project.name}} but what displays is the project.id

[see te image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRiiL.png)

Comment: Try to use an option value as  **[value]="project"** instead of **[value]="project.id"**. I hope this will help you out. Kindly check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ptfxxh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts for more references. @David Burgos

Comment: Thank you, it helped me!